# How do update AddJsonOptions in .NET 6 at runtime anytime I send a request

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, .net-6.0

I am working with `.NET 6` and `C#`.In the `startup.cs` file, I have this option that is executed when the application starts:

```
 services.AddMvc()
         .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver 
                                           = new CustomContractResolver(requestOption));
```

`CustomContractResolver` is a class derived from  `DefaultContractResolver` with a variable `requestOption` (real name is different) that should be taken from the API request.

I send this value in the API request in order to change the `ContractResolver` behaviour. My goal is to execute the `AddNewtonsoftJson` for any API request and not just when the app starts.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, what is the api endpoint and what is it doing? https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Are you sure what you did is not working? Seems like its correct.